# Can "who" serve complement in a relative clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

1: He is no longer the person **who** he was ten years ago.

2: He is no longer the person **that** he was ten years ago.

Does the first sentence sound natural? Can "who" serve as a complement in a relative clause?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Both options listed by the original poster sound natural to my (American) ear.  The "that" option sounds more natural to me than the "who" option.  A third option would sound just as natural to me:

> He is no longer the person he was ten years ago.

I would avoid the "who" option, because I try to avoid making choices between "who" and "whom".  Choosing between "who" and "whom" interrupts my thoughts, both when speaking (or writing) a sentence, and when reading a sentence.

In other words, the choice between "who" and "whom" is consciously learned, not natural (in American English).

Comment: Leaving the "who" out sounds far more natural to me: ` He's no longer the person he was.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can serve complement in a relative clause. And thus, both sentences are okay.

A sentence from the **American Heritage Dictionary** as mentioned in [GrammarGirl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-that)

> It is entirely acceptable to write either the man ***that*** wanted to talk to you, **OR** the man ***who*** wanted to talk to you.

The word *that* as a relative pronoun to mention a person has been quite common among authors.

However, I will go with GrammarGirl in this opinion of hers. It's interesting.

> To me, using that when you are talking about a person makes them seem *less than human.* I always think of my friend who would only refer to his new stepmother as the woman *that* married my father. He was clearly trying to indicate his *animosity* and you wouldn't want to do that accidentally.

Comment: All your examples sound fine, however the example with 'who' in the original question sounds unnatural.

Comment: @ Alan Third  Do you mean "He is no longer the person who he was ten years ago" sound unnatural?

Comment: @April you need to put @ symbol to notify Alan.

Comment: @april yes. I think it's probably OK English, but mostly you would hear *that* rather than *who*.