# Can “whom” serve as a complement in a relative clause?

Tags: relative-pronouns, case

Can “whom” serve complement in a relative clause?

Does the sentence "He is no longer the person **whom** he was ten years ago" sound natural?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use "that", not "whom".

Comment: I remember the same question here. Is this been posted one more time?

Comment: @MaulikV You are thinking about [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31392/32); but there the question concerns *who*, not *whom*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Whom* cannot serve as complement of *BE* in a relative clause (or anywhere else).

*Whom* is an objective-case form and can be used only when it stands as the object (direct or indirect) of a verb or preposition.

Thus, you may say

> He is no longer the person **whom** I **knew** ten years ago.

because *whom* is he direct object of *knew*. But in your sentence, the *wh-* form is a subject-oriented complement of *was*, and must take subject case: *who*.

What may be confusing you here is that in colloquial Present-Day English (and mostly even in written PDE), personal pronouns acting as subject-oriented complements take the objective form: *That was **me** ten years ago.* But that is a peculiarity of personal pronouns and does not extend to relatives. In fact, the opposite tendency is found with relatives: the objective form is well on its way to extinction.

My recommendation is that in bound relative clauses<sup>†</sup> where *who* is the complement of *BE* you omit it altogether. This is acceptable in all registers (∅ marks the point at which the relativizer is omitted):

> He is no longer the person ∅ he was ten years ago.

The relativizer may also be omitted whenever the *who* form acts as object of the verb or of a preposition left ‘stranded’ after the verb:

> He is no longer the person ∅ I knew ten years ago.
> He is no longer the person ∅ I played **with** ten years ago.

That will leave you only two cases where you have to worry about which form to use:

- In clauses where the relativizer acts as subject, use *who*<sup>‡</sup>:

  > He is no longer the person **who** led us to victory ten years ago.
- In clauses where the relativizer is object of an immediately preceding preposition, use *whom*:

  > He is no longer the person **with whom** I played ten years ago.

---

<sup>†</sup> Note, however, that in **free** relative clauses, where the clause acts as an NP rather than a modifier, the *wh-* form cannot be deleted.

> We do not yet know who did this.

The conventions in these cases can be tricky; if you want to know more about this I suggest raising it as a separate question.

<sup>‡</sup> When the relativizer acts as subject of a verb construction headed by *BE* it is often possible to omit both the the relativizer and the *BE* form. This is another tricky rule; it has been treated on ELU [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/24489). Again, if you would like to know more I suggest raising a separate question.